# Flash AS3 load external resources for android development

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am new to Flash to Andriod App through Adobe Air. I need to know if it is possible to load external resources.Will it work on andriod ?

For example I want to use structure like  and I want load/render menu from xml and use user images from /Resources Dir.

1. How will this work workout when this will be converted to .apk ?
2. will there still be resources folder on android ?

I am confused on Andriod thing because i want to make an APP which should update menu from xml , XMl which will be updated with user data and user images dynamically.

```
-- APP_DIR
   -- APP.APK/APP.FLA/APP.SWF
   -- menu.XML
   -- /Resources
      --/user1.jpg
      --/user2.jpg
```

**menu.XML**

```
<Users> 
  <item>
    <Name>Pelco</Name>
    <image>/Resources/user1.jpg</image>
  </item>
  <item>
    <Name>Jenuy</Name>
    <image>/Resources/user2.jpg</image>
  </item>
</Users>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. How will this work workout when this will be converted to .apk ?

> It will work same as flash does you do not have to follow any
>   directory structure when using flash for android.

1. will there still be resources folder on android ?

> No, but still you have a freedom to create your own, and you can access it using relative path.

The Above XML structure seems perfect, let me know in case your are facing any problem

Thanks,
Dhiraj

Comment: Ok.Thankx.I will build up a basic App and let you know.